# If let statement with multiple returns from function in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

Say I have a function

```
func function1() -> (result:Bool, data:String){

    return(false, "false")

}
```

and I want to use the return value of the Bool in an if let statement so,

```
if let value = function1 {
    //code
} else {
    //code
}
```

How would I get this to work? I can't seem to see it in the swift docs, as it just aludes to it being a returned tuple, which you can access with dot notation, but only if you set the return to be a tuple first - so for example this would work

```
var value = function1()

if value.result {
    ////code
} else {
    //code
}
```

works, but I'd like to fit it all into the actual if else if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the use of a computed property.

```
func someFunc() {

    if let value = computedProperty where value.result {
        print(value.data)
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}

var computedProperty: (result: Bool, data: String)? {
    return (true, "FooBar")
}
```

or using a function

```
func someFunc() {

    if let value = anotherFunc() where value.result {
        print(value.data)
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}

func anotherFunc() -> (result: Bool, data: String)? {
    return (true, "FooBar")
}
```

Hope this helps :)

[Swift 2.1 Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

Answer (score 1):

You could pattern match with a switch statement.

```
switch function1() {
  case (true, let string):
      print(string)
  default:
     // else stuff here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this type on `if` you need optional return type from your function like this:

```
func function1() -> (result:Bool, data:String)? {
    return(false, "false")
}

if let value = function1() {
    //code
} else {
    //code
}
```